# Bring SVG line to front, Uncaught InvalidCharacterError

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

https://gist.github.com/dukevis/9039575

I have a multi-line graph, and I want it to be so that when you hover over the legend box, the team you hover over retains their color while the rest of the lines go gray. This I've managed, however, I also want to bring that team to "the front" of the other lines.  I was able to successfully implement this when hovering over the lines directly by re-appending the selected line to the svg. However, when I try to do this from the legend box, I get an error saying: 
"Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: The string contains invalid characters."

The relevant piece of the code (or what I believe is relevant) is here

```
svg.selectAll("g.keybox").on("mouseover",function(){        
        var keepName = this.textContent;
        var selectedLine_box;
        svg.selectAll("path.team.line").style("stroke", function(d){
            if(abbrDict[d.name]!=keepName){
                return "#C0C0C0";
            }
            else{

                selectedLine_box = d3.select(this);
                return color(d.name);
            }
        });

        var pathNode = selectedLine_box.node();
        var len = pathNode.getTotalLength();
        var pos = pathNode.getPointAtLength(len);  


        svg.append("text")
                        .attr("id","tooltip")
                        .attr("x",w-55)
                        .attr("y",pos.y-3)
                        .text(keepName)
                        .style("font-family","sans-serif")
                        .style("font-size",14+"px");

        console.log(selectedLine_box);
        svg.append(selectedLine_box); //this causes an error saying "string contains invalid characters" and doesn't successfully re-append the line over the other lines



        });`
```

There's also a link to the whole code at the top of the page, and you can view the graph through the bl.ocks extension.

Thank you!

Comment: `.append()` expects a string, not a selection. You either have to use plain Javascript for this modification or use D3's [`.sort()` and `.order()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#sort).

Comment: How would I use plain Javascript to do this?

Comment: Something like `var node = selectedLine_box.node(); var parent = node.parentNode; parent.removeChild(node); parent.appendChild(node);`.

Comment: Thank you! I'd tried something similar to that before and failed to implement it correctly; I tweaked it around (I had to use the grandparent node and remove/append parent) and now everything works beautifully!